# Set NavigationBarColor on Samsung not working in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, bottom-navigation-bar

Setting navigation bar color is not working on Samsung Galaxy 20.

Here my set up.

```
themes.xml


 <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?attr/colorSurface</item>
</style>
```

The main activity class

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

And in `Theme.kt`

```
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
val colorScheme = when {
    darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
    else -> LightColorScheme
}

val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
DisposableEffect(systemUiController, darkTheme) {
    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = Color.Transparent,
        darkIcons = !darkTheme
    )
    onDispose { }
}

MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme = colorScheme,
    typography = Typography,
    content = content
)
}
```

It is working on all android studio emulators (Pixel 4, Pixel 5 and Pixel 6).
I have a NavigationBar as navigation feature for the app.
The area below the NavigationBar compose is indeed transparent and does not pick up the color neither of the NavigationBar compose (aka `colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(3.dp`)) when it is visible nor the surface color when there is no navigation bar compose within the screen.
The only physical device I have tested on is a Samsung Galaxy 20.
It is working on emulators as expected.

If I do something like

```
systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(3.dp`),
        darkIcons = !darkTheme
    )
```

then the navigation bar has the same color as the NavigationBar compose but then remains that way even on screen with no navigation bar, which is obviously not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix the issue by changing the code in my `Theme.kt` class to

```
 val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
 LaunchedEffect(systemUiController, darkTheme) {
    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = Color.Transparent,
        darkIcons = !darkTheme
    )
    systemUiController.isNavigationBarContrastEnforced = false
}
```

and of course in my values v7 themes.xml:

```
<style name="PlatformAdjusted.Theme.MyApp" parent="NightAdjusted.Theme.MyApp">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">?attr/isLightTheme</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">?attr/isLightTheme</item>
</style>
```